# how to Connect to Remote DB from vagrant box

Tags: mysql, laravel, vagrant, laravel-forge

I have a local  vagrant box I want to connect this box to the database server located on the forge server

My  .env  file on vagrant

```
DB_HOST= remote_server_ip
DB_DATABASE=forge
DB_USERNAME=forge
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

and on my /etc/mysql/my.cnf  file
bind-address = *

however when I try to open the site I receive
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

Comment: have you provided rights to forge user from remote location..

Comment: no , how can i do that  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your db server and execute below statement.

```
grant select,update,delete,insert,drop on your_db.* to forge@'your_ip' identified by 'your_password';
```

If you want to provide all rights and globally then below command-

```
grant all privileges on *.* to forge@'%' identified by 'your_password';
```

If still you are not able to connect remotely then check your iptables setting, you can either enable port 3306 from there or completely disable iptables service by below command as per your requirement-

```
$ service iptables stop
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out  , whatever i do

Comment: comment bind-address entry in your my.cnf and restart mysql service...if still you are getting issue then share some more information like your ip from where you are trying to connect db, results of "select host,user from mysql.user where user='forge'" and select host,user,db from mysql.db where user='forge'"...